# undeploying in tomcat 7 using ant task gives the error that POST is required, not GET

Tags: web-applications, ant, tomcat7, undeploy

when I try to undeploy an webapp in tomcat 7.0.30 using ant task, it gives me the message that

> FAIL - Tried to use command /undeploy via a GET request but POST is
>   required

But I could not find any solution for this problem.

Is my ant task is wrong? or tomcat config?

My ant task is...

```
<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${tomcat.base.dir}/lib">
            <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
            <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
            <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${tomcat.base.dir}/bin">
    <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<taskdef name="undeploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.UndeployTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
<target name="undeploy" description="undeploy from tomcat">
    <undeploy 
            url="http://localhost:8080/manager/html"
            username="admin"
            password="password"
            path="/mywebapp"
    />
</target>
```

And my tomcat-users.xml is...

```
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui, manager-jmx, manager-status"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this url instead of the one ending with "html":

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/text
```

You may also need to add these roles to your user in tomcat-users.xml:

```
manager-script, admin-script
```

Comment: Thank you so much! you just saved my project!